# Print statement failing to output on terminal inside nested loops/function

Tags: python, list, sorting, bubble-sort

This is my first question ever, so forgive me if I do something wrong.

I used Visual Studio to code a simple sorting algorithm this time, but I'm having a issue with it. I need to print the list of numbers not only to check if it is sorting, but also to see the final product. However, the terminal is not showing anything. Printing outside of the function, which has nested loops, works fine however. I tried to print a string as well, but nothing comes out. I assume I'm missing something simple, but I thought I would ask here since I've never asked a question here before. Thanks in advance. If there's any advice on asking questions, please don't hesitate to say.

```
bunny = 0
turtle = 0
temp = 0
sequence = [2, 8, 7, 1, 4]


def bubblesort():

    for x in sequence:
        turtle = sequence[x]
        for y in sequence:
            bunny = sequence[y]
            if sequence[y] < sequence[x]:
                temp = sequence[y]
                sequence[y] = sequence[x]
                sequence[x] = temp
                temp = 0
    return print(sequence)


print(sequence)
```

Comment: Are you ever calling bubblesort() ? You've defined the function, but I don't see when you call it

Comment: Also, you didn't directly ask about the functionality, but I'll point out that I doubt your for loops are doing what you want them to. The line "for x in sequence" will iterate through your vector, it won't return an index value, so instead of doing "turtle = sequence[x]", you could just do "for turtle in sequence:" in the first place

Comment: Ah right, I forgot to call the method, had a feeling it was something simple. Thanks! And yeah it's not working as it should, but I can fix that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on the comments saying the for loop won't iterate through indices, as expected, you can obtain the index through the "enumerate" method instead. I also made some refactoring: you don't need to declare bunny, turtle, temp at the beginning of the code, and I made it so bubblesort takes a vector as parameter instead of edit a global one.

```
sequence = [2, 8, 7, 1, 4]

def bubblesort(seq):
    for x, turtle in enumerate(seq):
        for y, bunny in enumerate(seq):
            if bunny < seq[x]:
                temp = bunny
                seq[y] = seq[x]
                seq[x] = temp
    print(seq)

bubblesort(sequence)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @polortiz40 mentions in his comment you are not showing the call to `bubblesort()` in your snippet. However I am going to assume you do.

I think your code never reaches the return statement of the function, because it crashes before that.

```
for x in sequence:
        turtle = sequence[x]
```

x will be: 2, 8, 7,...
At the second iteration you will be trying to access `sequence[8]` which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

First of all 3 things

- You didn't call the function `bubblesort()` then only the function will work.
- `return print(sequence)` in a function will return `None`, because you are calling the `print` function to return and by default `print` function only return `None` and which will be returned from your function. You can change it to two lines as below

  ```
   print(sequence)
   return sequence
  ```
- Your function has errors that you can see it after calling the function as in the below code.

  ```
   bunny = 0
   turtle = 0
   temp = 0
   sequence = [2, 8, 7, 1, 4]


   def bubblesort():

       for x in sequence:
           turtle = sequence[x]
           for y in sequence:
               bunny = sequence[y]
               if sequence[y] < sequence[x]:
                   temp = sequence[y]
                   sequence[y] = sequence[x]
                   sequence[x] = temp
                   temp = 0
       print(sequence)                
       return sequence

   print("After bubble sorting: ", bubblesort())
  ```

Instead of using the index value of list elements, you are using the value itself.